# ASP.NET Routing: Formatting the URL string

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing

I have implemented a routing functionality successfully in my project (a news website):

```
 Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("ndetails", "news/{title}/{id}/", "~/newsdetail.aspx")
 End Sub
```

and I set the URLs like this (databound to a repeater):

```
href="<%# Page.GetRouteUrl("ndetails", new with { .title= Server.UrlEncode(Eval("Title")), .id= Eval("NewsID")})%>"
```

The URL produced is like:

```
/this%20is%20a%20news%20item/89
```

As can be seen above, the URL part is difficult to read and I would like it to be like:

```
/this_is_a_news_item/89
```

I thought of going for a Replace function. But then, since the user creating the news might enter any string, I have to take into account all the other characters that might need to be replaced.

I just wanted to know from an experienced developer, whether going with a long replace function is the way to go, or is there another solution to format my URLs in this rouitng scenario.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no built in funcitonality in the framework to make url "pretty". You have to implement your own url fo rewriting the title.

In the save of your entities simply use a function that do the replaces that you need (' ' with '_' or example) and then use UrlEncode.
You can also use a Regular expression to do the replacement in one go.